# No such file or directory when run php artisan migrate on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu

i moved my laravel project from windows to ubuntu, i did everything required ( installing php, composer ...) then when i run php artisan migrate to create my database tables, it says:

```
In Connection.php line 664:
                                                                             
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from informa  
 tion_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)     
                                                                               

In Connector.php line 68:
                                                   
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

PS: i was using WAMP server for my database in Windows.

my .env DB config:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=blog
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: have  you  tried access your phpMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database seems to be missing the `migrations` table. You can create it by running

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

After that you will be able to run your migrations.

Comment: its says :
Connection refused (SQL: create table `migrations` (`  
  id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(25  
  5) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'ut  
  f8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: You did create your database 'blog' first, right? You can use `phpMyAdmin` (if installed) to create it

Comment: You'd also need to create your database user there, giving access to your database.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because `php artisan migrate` is trying to check the migration table from your database for the migration details, so it doesn't migrate old migrations files again, but since you want to create the tables afresh,

run this
`php artisan migrate:fresh`
this would clear the database and create all table afresh

or run
`php artisan migrate:install`
this would create the migration table ,
then run `php artisan migrate` to create all other tables

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: also check to be sure you have created the database `blog`

Comment: no i didn't create it , and when i run php artisan migrate:fresh it also says :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHER  
  E table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: you have to create the database first before running the migrations

Comment: is there any specific command to create my database named 'blog' please?

Comment: no you have to create it your self,  either by going through your phpmyAdmin or through the mysql cli

Answer (score -2):

- Use `127.0.0.1 for DB_HOST`
- Run php `artisan config:clear`

Comment: when i use ip adress it says : Connection refused instead no such file or directory

Comment: Always explain your answer. I'm curious what it would be when you suggest changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`...

Comment: Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer